How to solve the session pool occcupation stuck problem in Apache IoTDB?
Apache IoTDB often get stuck in SessionPool, and the system reported org.apache.iotdb.session.pool.SessionPool: current occupied size 50, queue size 0, considered size 50. After this information, the system also mentioned that SessionPool has wait for 60 seconds to get a new connection. I checked the official guide and did not find any relevant instruction for this kind of message.
How can I set and configure the parameters for this kind of problem?

This error is usually because the connection of Apache IoTDB is not released in your coding. Even though your data tasks are completed, the connection may not be released automatically, so you need to call close in your coding to release these connection to execute more tasks.
